# Set ListView ItemSource Binding in Code Behind Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I can't seem to get a straight answer for this problem.
Im trying to set the item source in the code behind. This is easy to do in the Xaml but seems to be not so straight forward in the code behind.

In the code behind I am using:

```
Binding listbind = new Binding("routeLabels") {Source=this};

listviewofroutes.ItemsSource = SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, listbind);
```

This just throws an error of "cant convert void to System.Collections.IEnumerable" I also think this isn't correct.

Im trying to bind it to an observable collection in the view model.

The view model:

```
private ObservableCollection<RouteInfo> _routelabels;
    public ObservableCollection<RouteInfo> routeLabels
    {
        get { return _routelabels; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _routelabels)) return;
            _routelabels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(routeLabels));

        }
    }
```

When setting the binding in the Xaml this binding works fine.
The issue is not observable collection the issue is that I have no idea how to set the binding in the code behind.

Summary:

I need to know how to do this (itemsource binding):

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewofroutes" ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}">


</ListView>
```

In the code behind.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To programmatically set binding on a control, you have to pass it as parameter in extension method. Reference links: [extension methods](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObjectExtensions/), or [member method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetBinding/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase/)

For example, try:

```
listviewofroutes.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "routeLabels")
//Or, 
listviewofroutes.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("routeLabels"))
```

This sets a binding between path as 'routeLabels' and control's `BindingContext` which is the view model.

Also, would recommend changing 'routeLabels' to 'RouteLabels' as per standard naming policy for C# properties.

Comment: I will give this a try. One moment.